# Selected cell's address is skipped when a user selects it from the Task Pane

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, office-addins

When a user selects a cell from a Task Pane, the selected cell's address is skipped sometimes.
This case is reproducible for quick clicks over the cells.
For details, see a video below.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TLLPbmPJotb60rAycyKuyssGnxw10lUE/view?usp=sharing

Do you know how to fix this issue or, maybe, it is a known bug and you plan to fix it in the nearest future?

Comment: It looks like a bug, would you please share the sample code for us, we would like to validate in our side. Thanks.

Comment: @RaymondLu
We used Script Lab for the bug catching, namely Single click event sample.
Below is a code part that is run when the click event is triggered

` $("#register-click-handler").click(() => tryCatch(registerClickHandler)) `

Comment: I just have a try on my side, it seems I am not able to repro this. my excel desktop version 130001, I also tried on Mac and excel online, all 3 platforms are not reproed.  may I know your excel version? can you have a try on excel online?

Comment: @RaymondLu
we used Windows 10, 64.
on the video is used the Online version (16.0.13017.37953).
The same issue is reproducible for Desktop version of Excel 365 (16.0.12827.20328).

Comment: I asked some of my colleagues to have a try, but no luck. what do you mean for "When a user selects a cell from a Task Pane"  may I know how you select a cell from a task pane?

Comment: Under the words "a user selects a cell from the task pane" I meant, that a clicked cell's  address is shown in the Task pane component.

Comment: @RaymondLu
We have recorded a video with a full flow of error catching. Maybe, it helps to reproduce the error on your machine.
1. Excel Online build version is shown (Windows Platform, Chrome browser)
2. Script Lab is downloaded from the Store
3. The Samples tab is opened
4. The Single click event is found
6. a user clicks over the cell on the spreadsheet. Pay attention to the console.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gYcZ9hFhsSYRTIkVUzF6xCzGTPGhLe4L/view

A user clicks on a cell, but the last record in the console is an address of the cell that was clicked previously.

Comment: The link for a video with the same error catching on the Desktop version of the Excel is below (Windows)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OFSd-0i-NVEYBx7fZfnGMUU6IsQ4gJol/view?usp=sharing
The link for a video with the same error catching on the Desktop version of the Excel is below (Mac mini)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16j0oMmFywKJ7yNCz_nXTtx_FrS-T1XKK/view?usp=sharing